# Bug: invalid underlying type name

Tags: codefluent

If you change the 'Underlying type name' property of an enumeration in something that does not exist (typo). The application throws an 'CF0230: Invalid enumeration type 'System.Int32System.Int16'.' Error. Which is fine.

However, there is no way to change the type afterwards. I had to edit the CFP manually to correct the error.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, we'll fix it quickly. SO is for general questions, to report a bug please use <http://www.softfluent.com/support/>

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that next time